# Generic Mergesort in C#

Tags: c#, sorting, constraints, mergesort

I am trying to implement a generic `Mergesort` algorithm in `C#`, but I am having difficulty with the `Constraints`. I have searched many references but I can't find any that are implementing the algorithm like I am.

[MergeSort algorithm in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15835805/mergesort-algorithm-in-c-sharp)

[Generic Implementation of Sorting Algorithms](http://blogsprajeesh.blogspot.com/2008/07/generic-implementation-of-sorting_17.html)

Anyways, I am trying to provide an implementation that only allows the user to Mergesort a dataset that inherits from the [`IComparable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.icomparable.aspx) interface.

Below is what I have so far:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace SortUtil
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<int> testList = new List<int> { 1, 5, 2, 7, 3, 9, 4, 6 };
            Mergesort.mergeSort<int>(testList); // Compiler Error at this Line.
        }
    }
    class Mergesort
    {   
        public static void mergeSort<T>(ref List<T> inputData)
            where T: IComparable<T>
        {
            mergeSort(ref inputData, 0, inputData.Count - 1);
        }

        private static void mergeSort<T>(ref List<T> inputData, int firstIndex, int lastIndex)
            where T: IComparable<T>
        {
            // If the firstIndex is greater than the lastIndex then the recursion 
            // has divided the problem into a single item. Return back up the call 
            // stack.
            if (firstIndex >= lastIndex)
                return;

            int midIndex = (firstIndex + lastIndex) / 2;

            // Recursively divide the first and second halves of the inputData into
            // its two seperate parts.
            mergeSort(ref inputData, firstIndex, midIndex);
            mergeSort(ref inputData, midIndex + 1, lastIndex);

            // Merge the two remaining halves after dividing them in half.
            merge(ref inputData, firstIndex, midIndex, lastIndex);
        }

        private static void merge<T>(ref List<T> inputData, int firstIndex, int midIndex, int lastIndex)
            where T: IComparable<T>
        {
            int currentLeft = firstIndex;
            int currentRight = midIndex + 1;

            T[] tempData = new T[(lastIndex - firstIndex) + 1];
            int tempPos = 0;

            // Check the items at the left most index of the two havles and compare
            // them. Add the items in ascending order into the tempData array.
            while (currentLeft <= midIndex && currentRight <= lastIndex)
                if (inputData.ElementAt(currentLeft).CompareTo(inputData.ElementAt(currentRight)) < 0)
                {
                    tempData[tempPos++] = inputData.ElementAt(currentLeft++);
                }
                else
                {
                    tempData[tempPos++] = inputData.ElementAt(currentRight++);
                }

            // If there are any remaining items to be added to the tempData array,
            // add them.

            while (currentLeft <= midIndex)
            {
                tempData[tempPos++] = inputData.ElementAt(currentLeft++);
            }

            while (currentRight <= lastIndex)
            {
                tempData[tempPos++] = inputData.ElementAt(currentRight++);
            }

            // Now that the items have been sorted, copy them back into the inputData
            // reference that was passed to this function.
            tempPos = 0;
            for (int i = firstIndex; i <= lastIndex; i++) {
                inputData.Insert(firstIndex, tempData.ElementAt(tempPos));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`My issue:` I am getting a Compiler error in the Main method of the Program class; however, shouldn't I have to supply the *mergeSort* function the parametrized type when I call it statically?

I am getting the error `"The best overloaded method match for... has some invalid arguments."`

I would greatly appreciate any implementation suggestions and/or any way of correcting this error. Note, I am most comfortable in Java, and since C# doesn't directly support wildcards this approach is foreign to me. Any explanations on this would be appreciated as well.

Comment: Remove all usages of `ref` and proceed as normal. `ref` uses *Call By Reference* semantics (i.e. *assignments* to the variable will reflect in the caller), when C# normally (and sufficiently here) uses [*Call By (Object) Sharing*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy#Call_by_sharing) semantics. Remember that when a Reference Type is passed it is *not* copied/cloned/duplicate. For an example of when `ref/out` may be useful, see `int.TryParse`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could remove `ref` from all of your parameters since you do not seem to be using its functionality.

Also you would not need to provide generic parameter type in most cases because the compiler will infer the type for you. So this should work (assuming you've removed `ref` from the parameters) in most cases:

```
Mergesort.mergeSort(testList);
```

Also `List<T>` and arrays have indexers so you can get at specific elements via `inputData[index]` instead of `ElementAt`. It's just less typing that way.

Comment: Indeed. Best is to not use `ref` (especially when the behavior is not understood/needed). I've seen many people add it because they believe it "passes the reference to .." allowing shared modification or some such - perhaps from a VBA background?

Answer (score 1):

`MergeSort` reuires a [`ref`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14akc2c7.aspx) parameter, so it needs the `ref` keyword. This should work:

```
Mergesort.mergeSort<int>(ref testList);
```

> The ref keyword causes an argument to be passed by reference, not by
>   value. The effect of passing by reference is that any change to the
>   parameter in the method is reflected in the underlying argument
>   variable in the calling method. The value of a reference parameter is
>   always the same as the value of the underlying argument variable.

Comment: Good catch Tim! That one was slipping my eye.